# Can a person be described as "dishonest but scrupulous"?

Tags: word-usage, difference, synonyms

I am trying to comprehend the difference between the usage of "dishonest" and "unscrupulous". I understand unscrupulous refers to a person who is unprincipled, and dishonest is a person who is not honest. So can there be a person who is dishonest but scrupulous? I am thinking of a person like Robin-hood.

Comment: If you aren't confusing multiple meanings of each word, it's not clear which meanings you're thinking of. For instance, *scrupulous* can mean "having moral integrity" or "exacting". And "dishonest" can mean "lacking truth," "untrustworthy," or "deceptive" (each having a different nuance of meaning.)  In the case of Robin Hood, are you asking if he can be both moral and dishonest? It would depend on what you mean by "moral." Some people think that to be moral you have to always tell the truth. Others think that being moral doesn't have to mean that …

Comment: Someone could be dishonest about money but scrupulous about keeping their fingernails clipped short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrupulous and unscrupulous are a slightly odd pair of words.

Unscrupulous does mean "having not moral principles", so it goes naturally with dishonest.

Scrupulous, however, has as it's principal meaning "careful and attentive to detail", and as a secondary meaning "careful to avoid doing wrong". Neither fits "Robin Hood", who is also not "dishonest". Robin Hood is an outlaw, and a thief, not a liar.

Dishonest and scrupulous could mean an accountant that carefully falsifies a company's records to evade tax.  The accountant is very careful and attentive to detail, so scruplous in that sense, but also dishonest. Indeed you could say that that accountant is both scrupulous and unscruplous!

It is unlikely that you would say "dishonest and scrupulous" except in made up contexts.